# Concatenate multiple rows to one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, string-concatenation

I have a SQL Server output which returns the following values with one column:

```
RepresentID 
---------------
111122222
3333344444
5555566666
000000090909
7777788888
9999999999
121212131313
141414151515
```

Output :

```
RepresentID
---------------
111122222
3333344444
5555566666
000000090909
7777788888
9999999999
121212131313
141414151515
```

Comment: What's your expected output

Comment: I need to concatenate all the rows in to one row.

Comment: Show ur query plz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Answer (score 1):

> need to concatenate all the rows in to one row.

use xml path like below

```
 SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT
            ','+cast(representid as varchar(30))
        FROM
          table 
        FOR
            XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
    ) AS comma_seperated_list;
```

On sql2017 , you can use string_aggregate like below

```
select string_agg(cast(representid as varchar(40)),',')
from table
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but to get a line break between each element instead of a comma-separated list, you can use replace the comma with CHAR(13) (carriage return), CHAR(10) (line feed), or CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) (CRLF).